# Get all records between two different composite primary keys

Tags: oracle, composite-primary-key

I have a table which has a composite primary key(pk with multiple columns) in oracle. I am running a SAMPLE query to get random primary keys.

> SELECT
>       col1,
>       col2,
>       col3,
>       col4
>   FROM
>       table SAMPLE ( 0.1 )
>   WHERE
>       col1 = 'XXXXX'
>   ORDER BY
>       col2,
>       col3,
>       col4;

And a sample output will be something like

```
XXXXX   1   YYY A
XXXXX   2   ZZZ a
XXXXX   3   AAA b
XXXXX   4   BBB c
XXXXX   5   CCC c
XXXXX   6   DDD c
XXXXX   7   EEE i
```

Now, I want to get all the rows between first 2 primary keys and then next 2 primary keys

Answer (score 1):

Well the general pattern would be:

- If `col1` of a row is less than the compared value for `col1` then the row is "lower" i.e. more up front if sorted.
- If `col1` of a row is equal to the compared value for `col1` and `col2` of that row is less than the compared value for `col2` then the row is "lower" i.e. more up front if sorted.
- ..

What would lead to an expression like:

```
col1 < '?'
 OR col1 = '?'
    AND col2 < '?'
  OR col1 = '?'
     AND col2 = '?'
     AND col3 < '?'
   OR col1 = '?'
      AND col2 = '?'
      AND col3 = '?'
      AND col4 < '?'
    OR col1 = '?'
       AND col2 = '?'
       AND col3 = '?'
       AND col4 = '?'
```

(I didn't use your values, honestly they confuse me. Replace the question marks appropriately.)

The pattern for the other direction is analog. Just make `>` out of the `<`. Then `AND` the both sub expressions. Don't forget to put parenthesis around each of them, to force the `OR`s to precede (`(< sub expression for <= >) AND (< sub expression for >= >)`.

You may want to try to use Boolean algebra to simplify that if possible. (This time I'm just too lazy to try and do that. And the pattern is more recognizable that way.) But since this a simple task for the optimizer which might change it if possible and promising anyway, there's not much benefit from it other than maybe a better (human) readability.

Comment: Thanks @sticky bit, I have posted my query following your suggestion. hope that is how it works